# Hash map of struct keys and getter functions

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a nested struct (simplified):

```cpp
struct Person {
  struct JobDetails {
    std::string company_name;
    std::string address;
  };

  JobDetails job_details;
  int32_t age;
  std::string name;
};
```

Is it possible to create a hash map of keys and getters (functions) for each struct field, even for nested ones?

E.g.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, ???> hash_map{
  "company_name", [](Person const& person) { return person.job_details.company_name; },
  "age", [](Person const& person) { return person.age }
};

auto value = hash_map["company_name"](person);
```

Comment: As you would need to access records by other means (at least by name), I would recommend to use `boost::multiindex` - which avoids duplicates of fields and allow to create indexes for various fields.

Comment: @Slava A `boost::multiindex` would be very useful as a container of `Person` objects, but would it help as a container of getter functions?

Comment: @aschepler probably for that purpose it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat. You'll want `std::function<something>` as the map's value type to be able to store a variety of lambdas. The harder issue is that every expression must have a single type known at compile time. If I have a `std::string key;`, then the expression `hash_map[key](person)` could be either a `std::string`, or an `int32_t`, or possibly other types.

Maybe you could instead have a map of string property functions, a different map of numeric property functions, and more if needed.

Or if you really want a single map storing multiple value types, a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might help.

```
using PersonProperty = std::variant<std::string, std::int32_t>; // more?
using PersonPropertyGetter = std::function<PersonProperty(Person const&)>;
std::unordered_map<std::string, PersonPropertyGetter> hash_map{
    { "company_name", [](Person const& person) { return person.job_details.company_name; } },
    { "age", [](Person const& person) { return person.age } }
};
```

Then you'll need to use `std::visit` or `std::get` or `std::get_if` to actually use the `std::variant`.

```
std::visit([&prop_name](auto const& value)
                { std::cout << prop_name << ": " << value; },
           hash_map[prop_name]);
std::visit(overloaded{
    [](std::string const&) { std::cout << " (string)\n"; },
    [](int32_t) { std::cout << " (int32_t)\n"; } });
auto prop_value = hash_map[prop_name];
if (std::string const* str_value = std::get_if<std::string>(prop_value))
    do_a_string_thing(*str_value);
int32_t age = std::get<int32_t>(hash_map["age"](person)); // Throws if wrong type!
```

The `overloaded` tool used in one example is defined in the example at the cppreference page for [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). Just put in a convenient header file:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```